# Using HTML to insert data into an SQL server table

Tags: html, mysql, sql, database

A little background info:
I am using Netbeans IDE 7.3, I have an SQL server running and I am **trying to create a html application to insert data into the connected sql server**/database structure.

I hope that made enough sense to see what I'm asking.

> My question:  I simply want to create a page on the HTML application
>   which asks a user to enter information about a person such as their
>   first name, last name, address, phone number, etc.

I want it to appear in this manner to the user:

First Name: [text area]

Last Name: [text area]

etc....

Then at bottom I want a submit button.
At this point the information in the fields above would be sent to the "person" table in the database with each column/attribute filled with the appropriate information above.

**A new row is created in the table at this point.**

How can this be done? Examples of code would be great if you know of any.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

That cannot be done with HTML alone, you'll need a scripting language like PHP to do the job.

Comment: Just to clarify, you need a server-side scripting language. You can build the form in HTML, then submit it with HTML or javascript, but that only gets the data to the web-server. SQL servers are their own piece of software and do not directly communicate with a client (browser). So you need PHP, ASP, JSP, or some similar server-side technology to handle connecting to the database itself.

Answer (score 0):

Build a form and use PHP to process it (or some other scripting language, I use PHP):

```
<form method="post" action="path_to_script.php">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
    if(isset($_POST['username'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
    }

    // Use $username as a parameter in your query

$stmt = $yourDatabaseConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO yourTableHere (usernameColumn) VALUES (:username)");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);

$stmt->execute();
```

[Learn more about prepared statements here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)